# JSP link to another JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my JSP page I want the links to forward to another JSP page. When the user is on the home.jsp I want them to go to login.jsp etc. The problem I am having is that the JSP can't be found except when i put the pages in the project folder (above the WEB-INF folder).

I tried these lines of code, but none worked:

```
<a href="/enq/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp">
<a href="/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp">
<a href="/pages/login.jsp">
```

It is only working with the JSP pages in the project folder and then I use the next line:

```
<a href="login.jsp">
```

But I want the JSP pages to be in: WEB-INF/pages/

Comment: WEB-INF directory is a private area of the web application, any files under WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly by specifying the URL like `http://somesite/WEB-INF/someresource.html`. Web container will not serve the content of this directory. However the content of the WEB-INF directory is accessible by the classes within the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it, I have created 4 Servlets for each JSP page. Every servlet forwards the message to the corresponding JSP like this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/enquette.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And in the JSP page in between the a href :

```
<a href="/enq/enquette">
```

The web XML:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Enquette</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/enquette</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="/pages/login.jsp">
```

It must work properly. What HTTP status do you get in this case?

Comment: I get this: HTTP Status 404 - /pages/home.jsp. Description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: How do you want  to send this request? From your `home.jsp`? Clarify structure of location your pages and paths to them.

Comment: I have a folder called enq (project name). In enq i have WEB-INF and in there i have classes, lib, pages and the web.xml. In the web.xml i have declared my Servlet. In the servlet i only do the next line of code: request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp").forward(request, response); which will get me on the home.jsp.

Comment: Use `request.getRequestDispatcher("pages/home.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: That doesn't work, I have to specify the WEB-INF or I get the same HTTP error, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You shouldn't specify WEB-INF and if you get 404 status it means that the path's wrong. Directory `pages` doesn't have this page or you make forward from a page placed in same directory. In this case you need use `request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Answer (score 2):

if you want the user have access to the following file:
/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp

you should create a servlet and you should change the link in the html or jsp file:

```
<a href="/pages/login.jsp"> login page </a>
```

create a servlet :
add this lines to your web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>accessFiles</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>accessFiles</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>yourclass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then create yourclass.java which extends a servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class yourclass extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

 private String message;

  public void init() throws ServletException
  {

  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/" + pathInfo).forward(request, response);

  }

  public void destroy()
  {
      // do nothing.
  }
```

}

getPathInfo() will return the part of URL after the servlet pattern (/pages/)
That should work.

You can also more jsp files under the /WEB-INF/pages/ directory and forward the user through this servlet to desire page.