# From one jsp link to another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

In first jsp page i want a link forward to second jsp file. How can i do that.Both jsp files are in same folder.My folder structure as follows.

```
WebContent
  jsp
    first.jsp
    second.jsp
```

in my first.jsp

```
<div>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="second.jsp" >click</a></li>
    .
    .

   </ul>
  </div>
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: You need to be considerably more detailed than "doesn't work". What happens when you click the link? If you get an error message, what is it?

Comment: Had u checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297122/jsp-link-to-another-jsp?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need the context path of the Web application. Try this:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/second.jsp" >click</a>
```

Comment: Regardless of the (incorrect) terminology they've used, it seems clear from the posted HTML that they want an anchor (`<a>`) element that points to the other JSP, rather than an automatic forward from one to the other.

Answer (score 5):

in your web.xml file map your jsp file:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>second</servlet-name>
     <jsp-file>second.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>second</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/secondJsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The following will work then

```
<li><a href="secondJsp" >click</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common practice would be to create a servlet that would redirect to the second.jsp and then link the servet URL.